# Generalization of the Sherman–Morrison formula to $I_d + u u^T+vv^T$?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, inverse

I know that, by the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), under some reasonable assumption on $u\in\mathbb{R}^d$, I we have that
$$
(I_d + u u^T)^{-1} = I_d - \frac{uu^T}{1+\lVert u\rVert_2^2}
$$
In other terms, we have a simple formula for the inverse of the sum of the identity matrix and a rank-1 matrix.

Is there a similar formula when one adds *two* rank-1 matrices? I.e., an expression for
$$
(I_d + u u^T+ v v^T)^{-1} 
$$
where $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^d$, as a function of $u,v$ ("separately")?

**Note:** $u u^T+ v v^T$ has rank $\leq 2$, of course. However, what I want doesn't seem to follow from the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), which "loses" the separate dependence on $u,v$ (or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the Woodbury matrix identity, in fact.  Note that your matrix can be expressed as
$$
I + uu^T + vv^T = I + \pmatrix{u&v}\pmatrix{u&v}^T.
$$
That is, with the [formula as presented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) in your link we can set $A = I_d$, $C = I_2$, and 
$$
U = V^T = \pmatrix{u&v}.
$$

Comment: Oh my, do I feel dumb. I'll accept this after I am back from lunch.